# how to group same elements when iterating array (e.g.:{1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,2,2})?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, iteration

For example, I have array {1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,2,2}, I want to iterate it to print something like it:

```
1 
2 2 2 
1 1 1 
3 3 
2 2
```

so I create a program like it (simplified from real code):

```
int numArray[]={1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,2,2}; //in real code it may be something like MyObject myObjectArray[]
vector<int> store;
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(numArray)/sizeof(int);i++){
    //in real case it may check store.back()!=myObject.getNum()
    if(store.size()>0 && store.back()!=numArray[i]){
        for(int j=0;j<store.size();j++){
            printf("%d ",store[j]);//(it may be someFunction(store[j]) in real cases)
        }
        printf("\n"); //(it may be changePattern() in real case)
        store.clear();
    }
    store.push_back(numArray[i]);
}
for(int j=0;j<store.size();j++){
    printf("%d ",store[j]);
}
printf("\n");
```

but this program is not very maintainable, first,it needs additional vector to copy and store some temp result,also, this code:

```
for(int j=0;j<store.size();j++){
    printf("%d ",store[j]);
}
printf("\n");
```

needs to appear both inside and outside for loop.

Is it possible to have some simple for loop like:

```
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(numArray)/sizeof(int);i++){
    if(//something like numArray[i]!=numArray[i-1]){
        for(//start from last changed element to current element){
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

which does not need to store temp results and no need to repeat codes?

Comment: I have seen many answers for your problem or situation and some of them are very good, some even use the auto keyword, others were using the stl library with specific algorithms. The answer I provided goes back to basic programming. When you start to use a for loop with a nested if loop with another nested for loop, this is where you would want to use a while loop instead. Check out my answer it should provide you with some very good insight.

Answer (score 5):

I'm very surprised that none of the answers so far have attempted to use the standard library.

The function [`std::adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) is used to find two consecutive items in a sequence that are the same; we want to do the opposite, which is to find two items in a sequence that are *different*. This is as easy as passing a negating predicate (i.e. `std::not_equal_to`) to `adjacent_find`.

Using this, the full solution comes out like so:

```
constexpr int numArray[] = {1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,2,2};

// Initialise the iterator
auto first = std::cbegin(numArray);

while (first != std::cend(numArray)) {
    // adjacent_find returns the *first* of each pair it finds....
    auto iter = std::adjacent_find(first, std::cend(numArray),
                                   std::not_equal_to<>{});
    // ...but we want the second member of each pair, as long as that's
    // not past the end of the array
    if (iter != std::cend(numArray)) {
        iter = std::next(iter);
    }

    // Print the array slice, followed by a newline
    std::copy(first, iter, std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout});
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Move on
    first = iter;
}
```

This prints

```
1
222
111
33
22
```

as required

Comment: Using `std::adjacent_find` is a good idea, hadn't thought of it.

Comment: @Kupiakos well then the usual thing is to give credit, rather than editing your answer to copy this one

Comment: I'm not familiar with the etiquette here. Should credit be put in a comment, in the edit description (which I did), or in the answer itself?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to group numbers in any way to obtain the desired output. All you need is to print `'\n'` every time when you discover that `numArray[i] != numArray[i-1]`

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 11 ; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && numArray[i] != numArray[i-1]) {
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << numArray[i] << " ";
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/BrRLvJ)

Comment: While perfectly fine for this problem, it doesn't solve the general problem of finding groups of contiguous elements when iterating an array.

Comment: I went with a different approach in my provided answer; I used a while loop instead; and I also addressed the problem for grouping similar consecutive items.

Comment: @Kupiakos Of course it does: all you need to do is to replace printing with saving the number in a collection, and printing `endl` with saving a collection in a list of groups.

Answer (score 1):

Using iterators and lambdas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <class Iterator, class Func, class BinaryPredicate>
void group(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Func callFunc, BinaryPredicate breakCondition)
{
    auto endgroup = begin;
    while (endgroup != end)
    {
        auto begingroup = endgroup;
        endgroup = std::adjacent_find(endgroup, end, breakCondition);
        if (endgroup != end)
            endgroup = std::next(endgroup);
        callFunc(begingroup, endgroup);
    }
}

template <class Iterator, class Func>
inline void group(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Func callFunc)
{
    ::group(begin, end, callFunc, std::not_equal_to<>{});
}

int main()
{
    int v[] = {1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,2,2};
    ::group(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
        [](auto start, auto end){
            while (start != end)
                std::cout << *start++ << ((start == end) ? "" : " ");
            std::cout << std::endl;
        });
    return 0;
}
```

This has the advantage of working with any forward iterating container of any comparable type, and can use any function that takes a begin and end iterator. The function is given iterators which point to the beginning and past-the-end of the group, like vector iterators. It can then do anything it wants with the group, including editing. You can also pass another group-break condition, like using `std::greater<>{}` to group only ascending elements.

Comment: `std::adjacent_find` usage courtesy of @TristanBrindle

Comment: Nice reusable code; completely differs from my answer and approach. In my provided answer; I went back to programming basics of simple loops and logic flow.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
const size_t len = sizeof(numArray) / sizeof(int);
for (size_t start = 0; start < len; ) {
    for (size_t ii = start; ii < len && numArray[ii] == numArray[start]; ++ii) {
        printf("%d ", numArray[cur]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    start = ii;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int group_start = 0;
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(numArray)/sizeof(int);i++){
    if (i > 0 && numArray[i] != numArray[i-1]) {
        printf("\n");
        group_start = i;
    }
    if (i != group_start) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("%d", numArray[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

This solves your toy problem, although it may not precisely solve the real problem, depending on what it is. In any case, you definitely don't need to store a temporary list of items; you only need the index of the first item in the group you're making. In this example, the items can be printed out as we go, and the start index is only used to space things out properly (which your example code fails to do, in a minor way — it prints a space before the newline). But if you were doing something more complicated that requires looping over the items after the fact, `group_start` and `i` give you the range that you need to loop over.

There is one bit of code that needs to be duplicated, which is the `printf("\n")`, but that's not a very big deal. If you have anything more complicated in there that you want to avoid duplicating, simply put it in a function, and the only thing you will have to write twice is the function call.

Answer (score 0):

This was a brain scratcher for me, so I came up with this pseudocode to do it. Not sure how correct it is, but it does pass the one test case:

```
var input = [1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,2,2]

if (input.length >= 2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
    if (input[i] == input[i + 1]) {
      print(input[i] + ' ')
    } else {
      print(input[i] + '\n')
    }
  }
  print(input[input.length-1] + '\n')
} else if (input.length == 1) {
  print(input[0] + '\n')
}
```

In Javascript (JSFiddle):

https://jsfiddle.net/efy1dr9x/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
int numArray[]={1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,2,2};
for(i=0; i<sizeof(numArray)/sizeof(int); i++) { 
    if(i==0)
        printf("%d ",numArray[i]);
    else if(numArray[i]!=numArray[i-1])     
        printf("\n%d ",numArray[i]);
    else  
        printf("%d ",numArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking about this too hard: there is no need to have any temporaries or to copy or move data unless if you need to keep records of repeated values or patterns. You can achieve this by working directly and easily from your existing container. Also when you find yourself beginning to use a for loop with a nested if statement with another nested for loop; this is when you should replace the entire code block with a single while loop with a few if statements. Sometimes it is best to go back to the basics and to do simple logic flow. Try this and let me know what you think.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Your Existing Array or Container
    int numArray[] = {1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,2,2};
    // Number Of Elements in that container
    unsigned numElements = sizeof(numArray) / sizeof(int);

    // Initial Index Value For Our While Loop;
    int index = 0;
    // Loop From Initial Index To Last Element
    while ( index < numElements ) {
        // Check To See If Index Is Last Element If So Break From Loop
        if ( index == numElements ) {
            break;
        }

        // First Do Not Check To See If The Value At Index & Next Are Equal, Rather Check
        // To See If They Are Not Equal. If They Are Not, Then Print The Value At That
        // Index And A New Line, Otherwise Just Print The Value At That Index And A Space.
        if ( numArray[index] != numArray[index+1] ) {
            std::cout << "numArray[index] << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << numArray[index] << " ";
        }
        // Increment Our Counter
        index++;
    }

    // We Are Now Done; Not Necessary To Create Temporaries Or To Copy Or Move Data
    // It Is A Little Easier To Read And Follow Logic Flow As Opposed To
    // Having For Loop -> Nested If Stated -> Nested For Loop & More...
    return 0;
}
```

All you need to do is follow the pattern or the flow of this while loop and it works very well. Loop through the size of your container, first check for the exit condition, then check to see what conditions are met to branch into what logical course of action you need to perform, then finally increment your counter. The only major difference here is I'm using a while loop instead of a for loop and I'm using the std::cout as opposed to printf().

Now if you need to group them you can add this to the same while loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int numArray[] = {1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,2,2};
    unsigned numElements = sizeof(numArray) / sizeof (int);    

    std::vector<int> group;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> groups;

    int index = 0;
    while ( index < numElements ) {
        if ( index == numElements ) {
            break;
        }
        if ( numArray[index] != numArray[index+1] ) {
            std::cout << numArray[index] << std::endl;
            group.push_back( numArray[index] ); // Add To Group
            groups.push_back( group );   // Add To Groups
            group.clear(); // Clear Group For Change In Value
            //std::cout << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << numArray[index] << " ";
            group.push_back( numArray[index] ); // Just Add To Group Do Not Clear           
        }
        index++;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Test Groups;
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++ ) {
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < groups[i].size(); j++ ) {
            std::cout << groups[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
} // main
```

Now if you want to make this more modular, reusable and generic you can put this into a templated function as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void groupObjects( unsigned startIndex, unsigned size, T* objectArray, std::vector<std::vector<T>>& groups ) {

    std::vector<T> group;

    while ( startIndex < size ) {
        if ( startIndex == size ) {
            break;
        }

        if ( objectArray[startIndex] != objectArray[startIndex+1] ) {
            std::cout << objectArray[startIndex] << std::endl;
            group.push_back( objectArray[startIndex] );
            groups.push_back( group );
            group.clear();
        } else {
            std::cout << objectArray[startIndex] << " ";
            group.push_back( objectArray[startIndex] );
        }
        startIndex++;
    }
}

int main() {    
    int numArray[] = {1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,2,2};
    unsigned numElements = sizeof(numArray) / sizeof (int);

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> results;
    groupObjects<int>( 0, numElements, numArray, results );

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < results.size(); i++ ) {
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < results[i].size(); j++ ){
            std::cout << results[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```